# DP Print (not count) all possible path classic climbing stair

Tags: dynamic-programming

I came across this classic question and found may many solution to it. for loop and DP/ reclusive + memorization.

Also found a twisted version of the questions asking to print all possible path instead of counting. Wondering for the twisted version, if we have DP solution ?

Q: If there are n stairs, you can either take 1 or 2 steps at a time, how may way can you finish the stairs. we can just using fib to calculate it. What if you are ask print out all possible ways(not revision please). For example, `if n = 5`. we have as solution. pseudo code is welcome or any language.

```
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 2]
[1, 1, 2, 1]
[1, 2, 1, 1]
[1, 2, 2]
[2, 1, 1, 1]
[2, 1, 2]
[2, 2, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

I have divided the solution into two subsections. First one using Memoization and the second one using Recursion.
Hope it helps!

1. Memoization Approach:  It uses an array and calculates forward the solution based on base condition. I am using an array of type string array to store all the possible paths. To add a new path we are performing cartesian using `Union`.

**Example:**

- To reach 1 we have path {1}
- To reach 2 we have two paths {1, 2}
- To reach 3 we have three paths {1 1 1, 1 2, 2 1} which is cartesian of above two paths.

**Note:** I have used two arrays just to make the solution understandable. We should be good with a single array.

[Demo Memoization Approach](http://rextester.com/LVR69369)

Full Program using Memoization Approach:

```
namespace Solutions
{
    using System;
    using System.Linq;

    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            // Total Number of steps in stairs
            var totalNumberOfSteps = 4;
            // Total Number of allowed steps
            var numberOfStepsAllowed = 2;
            dynamic result = ClimbSteps(numberOfStepsAllowed, totalNumberOfSteps);
            Console.WriteLine(result.Mem);
            Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", result.Print));
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static dynamic ClimbSteps(int numberOfStepsAllowed, int totalNumberOfSteps)
        {
            var memList = Enumerable.Repeat(0, totalNumberOfSteps + 1).ToArray();
            var printList = new string[totalNumberOfSteps + 1][];
            if (numberOfStepsAllowed != 0)
            {
                memList[0] = 0;
                printList[0] = new[] { "" };
                memList[1] = 1;
                printList[1] = new[] { "1" };
                memList[2] = 2;
                printList[2] = numberOfStepsAllowed > 1 ? new[] { "1 1", "2" } : new[] { "1 1" };
                for (var indexTot = 3; indexTot <= totalNumberOfSteps; indexTot++)
                {
                    for (var indexSteps = 1; indexSteps <= numberOfStepsAllowed && indexTot - indexSteps > 0; indexSteps++)
                    {
                        var indexTotalStep = indexTot;
                        var indexAllowedStep = indexSteps;

                        memList[indexTot] += memList[indexTot - indexSteps];

                        var cartesianValues = (from x in printList[indexSteps] from y in printList[indexTotalStep - indexAllowedStep] select x + " " + y)
                            .Union(from x in printList[indexSteps] from y in printList[indexTotalStep - indexAllowedStep] select y + " " + x).Distinct();
                        printList[indexTot] = printList[indexTot] == null
                                           ? cartesianValues.ToArray()
                                           : printList[indexTot].Union(cartesianValues).Distinct().ToArray();
                    }
                }
            }
            return new { Mem = memList[totalNumberOfSteps], Print = printList[totalNumberOfSteps] };
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
5
1 1 1 1, 1 1 2, 1 2 1, 2 1 1, 2 2
```

2. Recursive Approach

[Demo Recursive Approach](http://rextester.com/JVQ36163)

Full Program using Recursive Approach:

```
namespace Solutions
{
    using System;

    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            // Total Number of steps in stairs
            var totalNumberOfSteps = 4;
            // Total Number of allowed steps
            var numberOfStepsAllowed = 2;

            ClimbSteps(numberOfStepsAllowed, totalNumberOfSteps);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static void ClimbSteps(int numberOfStepsAllowed, int totalNumberOfSteps)
        {
            // Reach from [totalNumberOfSteps - [1..numberOfStepsAllowed]]
            ClimbStep(stepsAllowed: numberOfStepsAllowed, totalNumberOfSteps: totalNumberOfSteps, currentStep: 0, stepsTaken: String.Empty);
        }

        private static void ClimbStep(int stepsAllowed, int totalNumberOfSteps, int currentStep, string stepsTaken)
        {
            if (currentStep == totalNumberOfSteps)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(stepsTaken);
            }

            for (int i = 1; i <= stepsAllowed && currentStep + i <= totalNumberOfSteps; i++)
            {
                ClimbStep(stepsAllowed, totalNumberOfSteps, currentStep + i, stepsTaken + i + " ");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Ouput:

```
1 1 1 1
1 1 2
1 2 1
2 1 1
2 2
```

Comment: is this a DP solution ? new to DP, not sure if it is since new write code in c#  I have reclusive approach already.

Comment: I have added a DP solution. Hope it helps!